# How to assign default values ​to UI TextField, Select and checkbox material fields using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I need to assign default values ​​to a form that uses material UI and react-hook-form for form management.
The problem is that the values ​​of the select fields are not assigned and the values ​​that are do not activate the label of the TextField components

The following is how default values ​​are assigned:

```
 const val = result.result[0];
     const fields = {
     issuer_name: 'affiliatename',
     ct_name: 'technicaldata.Names',
     ct_surname_pat: 'technicaldata.PaternalLastname',
     ct_surname_mat: 'technicaldata.MaternalLastname',
     ct_casada_lastname: 'technicaldata.CasadaLastName',
     ct_position: 'technicaldata.Position',
     ct_telephone: 'technicaldata.Contact.Telephone',
     ct_mail: 'technicaldata.Contact.Mail',
     co_name: 'operationaldata.Names',
     co_surname_pat: 'operatingdata.PaternalLastName',
     co_surname_mat: 'operationaldata.MotherLastName',
     co_married_surname: 'operatingdata.MarriedLastName',
     co_position: 'operationaldata.Position',
     co_telephone: 'operationaldata.Contact.Telephone',
     co_mail: 'operationaldata.Contact.Mail',
   };
```

```
 for (const field in fields) {
    const value = getValue(val, fields[field]);
    setValue(field, value || '0');
   }

   function getValue(object, field) {
    const parts = field.split('.');
    let value = object;
    for (const part of parts) {
     value = value[part];
    }
    return value;`your text`
   }
```

These are some elements that are available:

iunpt text:

```
`<TextField
 error={errors.issuer_name ? true:false}
 label="Issuer"
 placeholder="Sender name"
 size="small"
 fullWidth
 {...register('issuer_name')}
/>`
```

input select:

```
`<div className="col-md-5 mb-3">
 <FormControl fullWidth size="small" error={errors.ct_position ? true:false}>
  <InputLabel id="ct_position_label">Position</InputLabel>
   <Select
    labelId="ct_position_label"
    label="Position"
    defaultValue=""
    {...register('ct_position')}>
    {positions.map((name) => (
     <MenuItem
      key={name}
      value={name}
     >
     {name}
    </MenuItem>
   ))}
  </Select>
 </FormControl>
</div>`
```

For text inputs it works but the label is not activated and the value is overwritten with the lable

And for the select it does not work, the values ​​are not set

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 issues, `Textfield` and `SelectBox` , so lets take a look at `Textfield` first :

If your `setValue()` does not trigger the label of MUI , that because the default value assigned to `useForm()` is `null` or `undefined`, change the default to empty string and that will do the trick for you :

```
const form = useForm( { defaultValues: { your_string_field: '' } } )
```

Your mentioned problem about `SelectBox` , should be fixed by handling `isOptionEqualToValue` and `getOptionLabel`  props of the SelectBox component, or another trick you can do , is to create a custom component and handle your **controlled selectBox** value with state just like the documentation, and after each time the state changes , you can call the `field.onChange()` method coming from `useController()` of react-hook-form